# Guid namespace is qXX

Tags: c#, wcf, namespaces

I have an simple WCF service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://mycompany.com", Name = "SomeContract")]
public class SomeContract : ISomeContract
{
    ....
}
```

There is an action inside contract :

```
public async Task<Guid> DoSth()
{
    ....
}
```

The problem is with generated WSDL:

```
<xs:element name="DoSthResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DoSthResult" type="q1:guid"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Why GUID has strange namespace `q1`? How to get rid of it?

Comment: Are you able to call your service? Is the `q1:guid` causing any issues?

Comment: @mjwills for me - no. But due to agreement (my company <-> client) WSDL should not contain such uneccessary things. I think that they are consuming WSDL with other programming language, so it maybe it cause problems at their side.

Comment: It is not "unnecessary". Other languages should not have a problem. It is just an autogenerated alias for `"http://mycompany.com"`

Comment: @bommelding ok, I see. But still - is any possibility to get rid of it?

Comment: Ok, but you said it is alias of full namespace. So if removing makes WSDL invalid, can I force to use full namespace?

Comment: What is wSDL.exe? Anyway - I cannot find any alias definiition inside XML. Pasted `q1` is the only place where it occurs.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.100).aspx